# Windows Azure Messaging Causes NALSECURITY EXCEPTION

Tags: c#, android, azure, xamarin, android-5.1.1-lollipop

I am using Windows Azure for the server side of my application.
The application is implemented in C# using Xamarin Studio
When the application is registering to Azure Messaging, calling

```
 NotificationHub.RegisterTemplate (deviceToken, templateName, template, expire, strs[0]);
```

I am getting an unclear exception that looks like it is coming from lower levels that the azure API levels:

This is the log:

> [System.out] Thread-31039 calls detatch() [AndroidHttpClient]
>   [NALSECURITY EXCEPTION] isMmsRequest() : CoreProtocolPNames.USER_AGENT
>   = NOTIFICATIONHUBS/2014-09 (api-origin=AndroidSdkAdm; os=Android; os_version=5.0;) [AndroidHttpClient] [NALSECURITY EXCEPTION]
>   checkMmsSendPermission() : isMmsRequest() = false method = POST
>   [System.out] Thread-31039 calls detatch() [AndroidHttpClient]
>   [NALSECURITY EXCEPTION] isMmsRequest() : CoreProtocolPNames.USER_AGENT
>   = NOTIFICATIONHUBS/2014-09 (api-origin=AndroidSdkAdm; os=Android; os_version=5.0;) [AndroidHttpClient] [NALSECURITY EXCEPTION]
>   checkMmsSendPermission() : isMmsRequest() = false method = PUT
>   [System.out] Thread-31039 calls detatch()

Can someone explain what is this exception, and what can be done about it - it seams that the registration with azure fails because of that.

Answer (score 0):

OK. It did take a lot of sweat to figure out...
There is probably a mistake in the documentation, but when I change the last argument from **string[]** to **String[]** it did the trick and the exception was not thrown any more.